# Visual Studio Emulator for Android hangs installing device profile

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator

I am running the Visual Studio Emulator for Android, but it's getting stuck creating a new device profile:

[image]

Are there any log files I can use to diagnose the problem, or does anyone from Microsoft have an idea what maybe wrong?

I'm running Windows 8.1 Pro, and it's the RTM version of the emulator installed with VS 2015.

Comment: I received the same message you did.  It produced a log file here: "C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\emulatormgr.android.log".

The error message in my log was:
[Critical] XDE Exit Code: InvalidArguments (3)

It listed the actual path and argument list in the message above it, but it's too long to paste here.

I'm unsure how to fix it.

Comment: @NightShovel - I wasn't able to fix this problem, and I no longer have access to that machine I'm afraid.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you are not yet a member of the "Hyper-V Administrators" user group. If you didn't restart your computer after installation, you should restart and try again.

If you've restarted and are still seeing this, go to Control Panel, then Local Users and Groups, and add your username to the "Hyper-V Administrators" group.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I was already part of that group.  I have been able to download and install new profiles, but it has stopped working for some reason.

Comment: I have the same issue and my user account was already in the Hyper-V administrators. I am going to try something else and provide feedback if it works.